# Preserve state in dll between succssesive calls from C++ application

Tags: c++, dll, state

I am explicitly using a [DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx) in my application, is it possible to preserve state in that DLL between successive calls to it? My attempts using a global have so far failed.

Would I have to use implicit linking for this to work?

Comment: Between successive calls from the same application instance should work. If you're talking about different application instances you'll need to write the state to a file or the Windows registry.

Answer (score 1):

The type of linking shouldn't have any influence here. It just defines when the DLL is loaded and if it's required to actually start your program. E.g. with runtime loading you're able to load DLLs that aren't there at compile time (e.g. plugins) and you're able to handle missing dependencies yourself. With compile time linking you'd just get a Windows error telling you there's a DLL missing.

As for the unloading, you don't have direct control wether your DLL will stay in memory, so it's possible it's unloaded between being used by two different programs. Also, what do you actually consider "successive calls"? Two calls from the same program? Two calls from the same program happening during two different executions? Two programs running at the same time? Depending on the scenario you might need some shared memory (or disk space) to actually pass data.

You might have a look at [DllCanUnloadNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to tell windows if you're ready to unload already, but depending on your use case this might be the wrong tool.